# Backbone doesn't update the template after a second render call

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a `Backbone` view and I'm using `Handlebars` to create template for the render method.

In my view I have a variable:

```
model  = [
        {key: '1', value: 'a'},
        {key: '2', value: 'b'},
        {key: '3', value: 'c'},
        {key: '4', value: 'd'}
       ]
```

I display several inputs and have the following events which listen:

```
'change input' : 'onInputChange'
$('.my-class').on 'keydown', (event) => @onKeydown(event)
```

So this is working fine. When the `change` event is fired I have some logic which updates the model according to the new input's value. And here is where the problem comes.

Both events are calling `render()` and I can verify that the last call i with the updated value, however if I change the input value and trigger the `keydown` event I don't see the change, if I trigger it again, then I get, even though `console.log(model)` shows that the model is already updated.

My render function looks like this:

```
render: ->
  @$el.html @template(model)
```

However if I wrap this in `document.ready` :

render: ->
  $(document).ready(() =>
    @$el.html @template(model)
  )

Then my template is updating properly.

My guess is that the fact that the `change` event can be triggered `onkeydown` so both are executed pretty much at the same time messes up with the `render()` execution, however I've tried to put a 1 second delay on the `change` event in order to be sure that the first call to `render()` has finished before I make the second call. Alas this didn't change the output I am still NOT getting my template updated. Only wrapping it in `document.ready` seems to solve the issue but I have no idea why thus I'm not sure this is the actual solution to the prbolem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a non delegated jQuery event listener,
`$('.my-class').on 'keydown', (event) => @onKeydown(event)`.

This won't work until the view/dom is rendered and matching elements are available(delegated events created by backbone will work even if view was in memory at the time of binding).
It'll also stop working once the view is re-rendered with new elements, unless re-binding is done.

^ There is a reason backbone provides easy way to use delegated event listeners (events hash). Using it should solve the problem